How to handle time to event data when there is a competing risk with very low incidence rate
I'm analysing time to event data. The primary outcome is time to discharge, and there is a competing risk of death. A competing risk model seems appropriate, but I was wondering if this still applies if the second event has a very low rate: less than 5% of the sample experiencing the event.
I was thinking of two possible alternatives:

Use a cause specific model and censor death.
Hypothetical estimand strategy: use a cause specific model and count death time as missing and impute a discharge time.


There's no problem in using a competing risks model here. If you only have a small number of death events then the coefficient estimates with respect to death will be relatively imprecise, but that will still be more information than you will get with your alternatives.
As the competing-risks vignette for the R survival package explains in Section 3.1, in a model with PCM and death as competing risks:

The same Cox model coefficients can also be obtained by fitting separate models for the PCM and death endpoint, censoring cases that fail due to the other cause. Hazards can be computed one at a time. When computing p(t), on the other hand, all the rates must be considered at once...

where p(t) is the probability of being in a given state at time t.
With a competing risks model you will get the  same Cox model coefficients for discharge as you would with your first alternative, but you will get a representation of the overall probability of discharge or death over time that wouldn't be provided by that alternative.
The second alternative bears some resemblance to the Fine-Gray model discussed in Section 4 of the vignette, in that it allows for an individual who already experienced one type of event to still be considered "at risk" in a way for the other event. I don't see any advantage in your alternative, however.
